# Avoid multiple parallel calls to same function getSessionToken

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, locking

I have a client side Javascript function that gets a session token. This token will expire at some point, and all my "threads" using it will call my `getSessionToken()` to renew it or get it initially

Now, how can I assure that the `fetch()` inside is called only once ? In some languages there is an atomic test-and-set call on variables. In other I can lock() a variable, and all other callers will wait.

I saw somewhere, that I should just return the same promise to all my callers. So I assume a `getSessionTokenWrapper()` that returns the promise it got and cached from `getSessionToken()`. But how do I make it atomic ? How can I be sure I do not have 5 concurrent calls to `getSessionTokenWrapper()` that all are in the state between testing promise, calling `getSessionToken()` and setting the promise ?

Comment: What exactly are you using for creating "threads"?

Comment: Async functions

Answer (score 0):

Async functions don't create threads. You are merely scheduling the execution of some instructions in the future. Unless a function uses `async/await` or is a generator it won't ever be suspended and resumed at a later point (and even in those cases it's not like the function is really interrupted, it returns a special value).

This is called "run to completion". From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

> This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be preempted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it may be stopped at any point by the runtime system to run some other code in another thread.

So if `getSessionTokenWrapper` is implemented like so

```
let cache = null;
function getSessionTokenWrapper() {
  if (cache === null) {
    cache = getSessionToken()
  }
  return cache
}
```

you can be sure that the first call with set `cache` and for any subsequent call `cache` will be set (assuming `getSessionToken` returns a value different from `null`).

---

And to provide a counter example with `async/await`: Because some instructions of an `async` function will be run at some point in the future, values can have changed in the meantime.

```js
let count = 0;

async function doSomething() {
  console.log('before', count);
  await Promise.resolve('some long running process');
  console.log('after', count);
}

const promise = doSomething();
console.log('increase count');
count += 1;
promise.then(() => console.log('done'))
```